# How to collect all possible contiguous string concatenations from an array of arrays of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find an efficient way to collect all possible contiguous string concatenations from an array of arrays of strings, excluding strings with duplicated parts. Example:

```js
var arr = [
        ["pq","bcd"], ["l", "ffnn", "xyz"], ["hm", "ffnn","ij"], ["ab","def","u","eeff"]
    ];
    function f(a) {
        var t = [];
        a[a.length-4].forEach(function(i) { 
            a[a.length-3].forEach(function(j) {
                if (j !== i) (
                a[a.length-2].forEach(function(k) {
                    if (k !== j && k !== i) (
                    a[a.length-1].forEach(function(l) {
                        if (l !== k && l !== j && l !== i) 
                        (t.push(i+","+j+","+k+","+l));
                    })
                    )
                })
                )
            })
        });
        return t;
    };
    console.log(f(arr));
```

where the result will be

```
["pq, l, hm, ab"],
["pq, l, hm, def"],
//...and so on...
["bcd, xyz, ij, u"],
["bcd, xyz, ij, eeff"]
```

(Note that while, e.g., `["pq, ffnn, ffnn, ab"]` is a possible combination, it is not included in the result because it contains a duplicate).
The problem is that I need to know the length of the array and write multiple nested functions correspondingly. But I need some function which will detect that length automatically, and return the desired result. Maybe it's possible to rewrite the above function using recursion, but I'm not sure if this would be the best approach to such a problem.

Comment: Side note: Using `map` when you're not using its return value is pointless and a bit of extra work (it creates an array for you that you then just throw away). Use `forEach` if you're not using the return value.

Comment: There will only ever be two dimensions? E.g., an array containing arrays? Not an array containing arrays of arrays?

Comment: @TJCrowder: Yes, I'll try to keep it as simple as "array containing arrays of strings".

Comment: do you want array as output?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use four for loops nested in each other.

I managed to get it.
It should work for n-subarrays.

Have a look and let me know if it doesn't work properly.

```js
var arr = [["pq","bcd"], ["l", "ffnn", "xyz"], ["hm", "ffnn","ij"], ["ab","def","u","eeff"]];
var length = arr.length;

var noDuplicate = function (arr, possibleDuplicate) {
    var arraySplit = arr.split(",")
    for (var i = 0; i < arraySplit.length; i++) {
        var arraySplitNoSpace = arraySplit[i].replace(' ', '');
        if (arraySplitNoSpace === possibleDuplicate) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};


var createLoops = function(original, adaptedOriginal, index) { // createLoops(arr, 0, 0);

    var temporaryResults = [];
    var temporary = adaptedOriginal ? adaptedOriginal : original[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < temporary.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < original[index+1].length; j++) {
            if (noDuplicate(temporary[i], original[index+1][j])) {
                temporaryResults.push(temporary[i] + ", " + original[index+1][j]);
            };
        };
    };

    if (index === length-2) { 
        var results = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < temporaryResults.length; i++) {
            results.push("[" + temporaryResults[i] + "]");
        }
        return results;
    }

    else {
        return createLoops(original, temporaryResults, index+1);
    };
};

var result = createLoops(arr, 0, 0);
console.log("result: " + result);
console.log("result.length: " + result.length);
```

Comment: This code has exactly the same problem as the code in my question: I will have to.write different functions for different lengths.

Comment: @lyrically I am working on the code that will work for n subarrays. I misunderstoord your question, sorry.

Comment: @lyrically wicked, check out the changes I made please.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, given an array of array of strings `n`, you want a list of all possible arrays `m` such that

1. for all `i`, `m[i]` is one of `n[i]`
2. for all `i` and `j`, if `i` != `j`, `m[i]` != `m[j]`

Well, break in half.

First, consider a function `combo` that given an array of array of strings, produces an array of the arrays that satisfy (1).  How do you write that?

`combo` on an empty input array produces an array containing only an empty array.

`combo` on a non-empty input array could work by taking the "head" (the first element of the array), and apply each string from the head in turn and prepending to every array in return value of calling `combo` on the "tail" (the rest of the input without the head).

Now go through that list and eliminate the entries with duplicates.

**Edit:** given the Tolstoivian length of some of the other suggestions, I thought I'd post my answer, which uses the [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library:

```js
const flatMap = (l, f) => _.flatten(_.map(l, f), true)

const combo = a => a.length?
    (v => flatMap(_.head(a), e => v.map(g => [e].concat(g))))
      (combo(_.tail(a))):
    [[]];

const allUniqueCombos = a => combo(a).filter(n => _.uniq(n).length == n.length)

var arr = [["pq","bcd"], ["l", "ffnn", "xyz"], 
          ["hm", "ffnn","ij"], ["ab","def","u","eeff"]];

console.log(JSON.stringify(allUniqueCombos(arr)))
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
```

(This is far from the most efficient use of CPU -- but computers are immensely less expensive than computer programmers.)